# Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания? 7

Tags: цитирование

Нужно ли в этом предложении тире перед "то" или, может, наоборот, правильно будет убрать двоеточие?

А если привести в пример широко известную фразу: «Каждый должен заниматься своим делом», то все обязательно с этим согласятся.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы! Оба совета приму к сведению.

Answer (score 2):

1) Я бы убрала двоеточие,  тогда это будет дословное высказывание **в роли несогласованного определения.**

А если привести в пример широко известную фразу (какую?) «Каждый должен заниматься своим делом», то все обязательно с этим согласятся.

2) Сравнить: А если кто-нибудь скажет: «Каждый должен заниматься своим делом», то все обязательно с этим согласятся. **Это прямая речь.**

**Разница в интонации**: в первом случае нет предупредительной паузы, а  во втором случае такая пауза делается после глагола со значением речи.

Answer (score 1):

**Если фраза не заканчивается цитатой, то после цитаты ставят запятую** (если цитата входит в состав деепричастного оборота или завершает первую часть сложного предложения) **или тире** (если цитата заканчивается многоточием, восклицательным или вопросительным знаком, а также если по условиям контекста отделять последующий текст запятой не нужно).

Если убрать цитату, то предложение будет таким:
*А если привести в пример широко известную фразу, то все обязательно с этим согласятся.*
Это означает, что в Вашем сложном предложении нужна именно **запятая** перед "то", а не тире (т.е. предложение оформлено правильно).

**Дополнение**

Да, можно, конечно, и без двоеточия:

***А если привести в пример широко известную фразу о том, что «каждый должен заниматься своим делом», то все обязательно с этим согласятся.***

Смысл предложения от этой "коррекции" не меняется, но оно становится, как мне кажется, проще для восприятия.